# Symfony 6: Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on string

Tags: php, html, symfony

Trato de subir una imagen con Symfony, pero al momento de almacenarla tengo ese error:

**Mi Input:** Hay otros valores, estos si llegan.

```
 <div class="col-12">
   <div>
     <input type="file" name="casafoto">
   </div>
 </div>
```

**Mi Controlador:** Hay otros valores, estos si llegan, importe todo lo que decía el ejemplo de documentación.

```
    //Esto es un el nombre de la imagen.
     $casa_foto              =  $request->get('casafoto'); 

    /** @var UploadedFile $brochureFile */
    $brochureFile = $casa_foto;

    // this condition is needed because the 'brochure' field is not required
    // so the PDF file must be processed only when a file is uploaded
    if ($brochureFile) {
        $originalFilename = pathinfo($brochureFile->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        // this is needed to safely include the file name as part of the URL
        $safeFilename = $slugger->slug($originalFilename);
        $newFilename = $safeFilename.'-'.uniqid().'.'.$brochureFile->guessExtension();

        // Move the file to the directory where brochures are stored
        try {
            $brochureFile->move(
                $this->getParameter('brochures_directory'),
                $newFilename
            );
        } catch (FileException $e) {
            //handle exception if something happens during file upload
        }

        $product->setBrochureFilename($newFilename);
    }
```

**Mi Error:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> **La documentación:**
> https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/upload_file.html

Comment: segun la documentación el $brochureFile lo obtienes desde el objeto formulario (si esta enviado y ha sido validado). En tu codigo lo estas intentando cojer desde $request->get(), que se usa para parametros de tipo texto, numerico y booleano. No sera que quieres hacer algo tipo $request->file() ???

Comment: Si, pero con file(), tengo este otro error: Attempted to call an undefined method named "file" of class "Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request".

Comment: prueba con: $file = $request->files->get('casafoto'); Puedes ver mas en: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18400216/how-to-get-file-upload-without-a-form

Comment: Ok, pero al imprimirlo con un dd($variable), tengo un null, como verifico que esta recibiendo datos?

Comment: en principio si te llega vacio es que no se ha enviado el archivo por el formulario. Por un casual tienes puesto el tipo de codificacion en el form?  si no tienes `enctype="multipart/form-data"` los archivos no llegan a php...

Comment: Esa es la solucion, gracias.